# Word for "putting an end to one's solitude" or "be with someone"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

In Arabic there is a one-word verb that approximately means "being with someone and not letting them be alone". It could be used in phrases like:

"يؤنس وحدتي "

"أنت تؤنسني"

"يؤنس وحشتي"

It is used in Arabic when someone is feeling lonely and you make them feel not so lonely anymore and make them feel safe .. it could be used in a romantic way..

The verb in Arabic is "يؤنس", it is transitive and usually takes 'loneliness'/'solitude' as an object.

Is there a transitive verb in English that has the same meaning?

Could it be that English speakers don't have this feeling because there is no equivalent/accurate translation?!

Comment: Nearly , It's forbidden to write in a un-english language .

Comment: Does it need to be more detailed than a word like *join* or *accompany*?

Comment: Chaperone maybe - http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chaperone

Comment: You probably mean *English*, the language, not *english*, the spin of a ball in billiards.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us what those Arabic phrases mean. That way, we might be able to guess _how_ the word is used, and from there think of how a corresponding phrase would be worded in English.

Comment: I have just edited the question @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: What is the romanized version of the word? It would be nice if you can include that as well.

Comment: What about "taking someone under your wing"? It might depend on the context.

Comment: @ermanen I am afraid this word/feeling doesn't exist in English

Comment: as for romanization it could be written: `anassa` (past tense) `yo'nisso` (present tense).

Comment: The idea of this word is beautiful. I know nothing of Arabic, especially not how to read it, but knowing that there is a word that describes a feeling that I have spent many years trying to describe is a comforting thought. Though I can't read this word, nor the phrases accompanying it, I can feel it, and I think this is what much of the world's communication is lacking - we spend so much time trying to define and translate, and not enough time trying to understand.

Comment: If English speakers don't have this feeling, why would you ask this on an English forum? You might want to learn a thing or two about the [Sapir-Whorf Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity) before suggesting that linguistic differences might precipitate intellectual or emotional differences to any great degree.

Comment: That there isn't one single morpheme for a concept in any given language doesn't mean those speakers are incapable of feeling it or even describing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you totally seeing that my mother tongue is Arabic, the word in Arabic has a meaning of human-to-human connection. for example, if you haven't seen someone for a long time you could say that to him, the correct literal translation would be something like 'humanize' even though that wouldn't make sense mainly because that in the English language they don't use it in such way, they don't have that kind of use for the word and they don't use it in the manner we Arabs do.. In Libya people call the bedside lamp وناسة because it's always there at night protecting, humanizing and looking out for them as if it was some kind of angel, impersonating the role of a human so to speak. Every language is different and this particular word is very unique and there are plenty of words in Arabic which I would strongly argue are not present in the English Language.. not in saying the English language is not as strong or profound.. no, but merely saying that every Language has a specific structure that pertains to a specific culture and environment so that is what in essence makes it unique from one another.. I would be immensely surprised if you do find an equivalent.. but also pleased if you do so you could share it with us :)

Comment: Finally someone who feels the difference! It is astonishing that the words/language we use define the limits of our feelings! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If they were sick, you could *nurse* them; if they were children, you could *mind* or simply *watch* them. In a bit of a stretch, you might perhaps be able to *comfort* or *guard* someone. If you don’t mind phrasal verbs — and you shouldn’t — then you could *watch over* or *look after* someone easily enough.

But I get the idea that you mean something more like *babysit* them, or the neologism *eldersit*. Then again, those have implications of age or the condition of the person in whose custodial care you would be, and I don’t know that is what you would want.

Most other verbs that could work there are not transitive, instead taking a preposition whose object is that person.  So you could *take care of* someone, or *tend to* someone.

Comment: I am sorry no, not in that sense.. it is used in Arabic when someone is feeling lonely and you make them feel not lonely anymore and make them feel safe, .. it could be used in a romantic way..

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for words like these :

["consort"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consort)

["intimacy"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/intimacy)

["bonhomie"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Bonhomie)

Comment: No, I am afraid none of the above is an accurate translation.. "To keep someone company" is closer, but it's not the same

Comment: Those look like nouns, not verbs.

Comment: No it is a verb, in the present tense it is: يؤنس

Comment: @Carpsen90 Then , Does my answer seem good to you ?

Comment: No sorry, it's not the same meaning/feeling.. Your name is arabic, I suppose you know the difference

Comment: "consort" is a verb also and means "to associate or keep company". It is close to what you are looking for.

Comment: No it's not the same, consort means to associate with (someone), typically with the disapproval of others.
"you chose to consort with the enemy"
synonymes: associate, keep company, mix, go around, spend time, socialize, fraternize, have dealings, run around, hang around/out, be thick

Answer (score 0):

If I have interpreted correctly your definition, an expression such as *affinity* could come close to the Arabic equivalent as in ***to have a special affinity***

> - [affinity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affinity)  a feeling of closeness and understanding that someone has for another person because of their similar qualities, ideas, or
>     interests

You could express the idea of no longer being alone, of ending one's solitude, feeling protected and safe, with a metaphor

> We sought and found shelter in each another
>   I found (my) [haven](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/haven) with [*name*]
>   He/she is my [anchor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anchor)/ [harbour](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/harbour) / [sanctuary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sanctuary)

Comment: It is more like how YOU feel when someone keeps you company.. and it's not necessarily used in a romantic way, so I wouldn't say it is like "having an affinity for someone".. it is a very fine detail in Arabic, it feels different when I try to put it in english words.. I have given up on trying to find equivalent words.. I just feel it.. and I wonder if there are things to be felt that I haven't felt yet

Comment: @Carpsen90  I believe that we all feel safe and protected when we are loved, and that love needn't be sexual or romantic. It could just be one of close friendship, a friend whom you trust deeply. Is that any closer?

Comment: I am so so sorry, but it's not the same meaning.. @Keffiyeh and Madeleine Feller came close the the feeling.. Anyway, thank you for your help :)